# How to set up user interface update for SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

We were trying to set up UI 2011 in Tridion. We have contacted  Tridion Support for the steps for installing Tridion UI 2011. They gave us a link for the documentation

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/concept_EDC411EF58BD4700A8B6BD996AB102F3 (login Required).

The documentation says how to Upgrade from Site Edit 2009.

- We have not installed Site Edit 2009 so can anyone suggest there is any way other than installing Site Edit 2009 and proceed with UI 2011
- We also followed the documentation and tried to set up Site Edit 2009 but it is not working. Pages are not displaying Site edit tool bar. When first time the page loads it shows Site Edit logo(flashes) then normal page loads. Do we need to modify some TBB to make it work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to install SiteEdit 2009 to instal the new User Interface in Tridion 2011.
The only prerequisite is to have installed the Hotfix Rollup HR1

Comment: I could not find a documentation on direct installation for UI 2011 in Tridion website. Were you able to perform a direct installation.

Comment: All my UI 2012 installations have been made without SiteEdit 2009. In the documentation link you give, there are recommendations of upgrading a previous SiteEdit 2009 installation, but you can skip this steps.

Comment: As a side note: According to the documentation, there is also a prerequisite to also have a Broker license (to use the session preview).  You wouldn't want to get to the end of an install and find out the client didn't have one!

Answer (score 10):

SDL Tridion World (https://www.sdltridionworld.com) contains all the documentation for installing any SDL Tridion product including UI 2011.

You will need a login to access this part of the website. If you don't already have access, then support should be able to set you up with a login.

This is the link to the UI 2011 documentation which contains all the release notes and installation manual.

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/documentation/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/index.aspx ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried hitting the second URL but it was not loading

Comment: Can you login to SDL Tridion World?  Once you are logged in, you should be able to navigate to Downloads > Documentation and then select UI Update 2011 SP1 from the list.

Comment: Thank you. I tried hitting the URL directly, was expecting a log in prompt then. I am able to view them.

Comment: Indeed, something wrong with that URL. Go to http://www.sdltridionworld.com, Login, then select from the Navigation Downloads -> Documentation -> UI Update 2011 SP1

Comment: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/documentation/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/index.aspx should work :-)